# Mess with an export PATH

Tags: terminal, path, bashrc

I have tried to include INTEL PARALLEL COMPOSER to my .bashrc.But something went wrong.Now I can not use gedit or vi editor.

```
milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~$ gedit .bashrc
Command 'gedit' is available in '/usr/bin/gedit'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
gedit: command not found
milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~$ vi .bashrc
Command 'vi' is available in '/usr/bin/vi'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
vi: command not found
```

How to edit .bashrc from terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have messed up your $PATH, which determines where bash looks for programs. Normally the user programs reside in /usr/bin and you should be able to run then with their full path instead of just the name: `/usr/bin/nano .bashrc` or `/usr/bin/vi .bashrc`.

Or you could run `export PATH=/usr/bin`, as recommended by Jeff in the comments.

Comment: or `export PATH=/usr/bin`